# The words "tailor" and "dressmaker"

Tags: word-usage

Historically, tailors who make men's clothes have been men, not women.
Can the word "tailor" be used for a woman who makes men's clothes? 
Or is there the rule that tailors are those who make men's clothes and dressmakers are those who make women's clothes, and both of these words are gender-neutral?
Thanks.

Comment: I believe these words are gender neutral in today's use however there is a gender specific word which is *seamstress*

Comment: Not a problem. My mother, who has been a dressmaker all her life, did a tailoring course when I was a child, 60 years ago, mostly so that she could make clothes for me and my brother. However, the techniques that she learned helped her to design and make women's fitted jackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These words do not refer to the gender of a tailor or a dressmaker, but to their specialization. So both nouns are gender neutral nowadays.